# pass dataframe in numpy vectorization function as an argument

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 30 columns. I am passing my dataframe to the function and returning values through numpy vectorization. However it`s not working and giving me an error that invalid index to scalar variable. T2 is constant with value 5000

```
def get_short_incl_MC_rules(df,T2):      
    return 'True' if(df['yield_rank'] < T2 and df['active_events_and_earnings'] == 1 and df['market_cap'] > 500 and df['net_income'] > 0) else False

vectFunc = np.vectorize(get_short_incl_MC_rules)
list(vectFunc(df,T2))
```

Comment: Please provide a complete and verifiable example as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what cant you understand? I believe it`s fully understanadable

Comment: vectorize passes scalar arguments to your function. Read and understand its docs first.

Comment: Oh okay got it.

Comment: @AliasgherNooruddin It is not the complexity of the question, nobody can edit your code to make it work due to data dependency which you don't provide...look at the link I provide how you ask a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain boolean masks together with `&` for bitwise `AND`, it is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and it is vectorized operation. Also for improving performance is added [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for comparing by numpy arrays:

```
def get_short_incl_MC_rules(df,T2):      
    return (df['yield_rank'].values < T2) & 
           (df['active_events_and_earnings'].values == 1)  & 
           (df['market_cap'].values > 500)  & 
           (df['net_income'].values > 0)

out = get_short_incl_MC_rules(df,T2)
```

Comment: Not this way, I need to apply numpy vectorization on it

Comment: @AliasgherNooruddin - What is reason? Chaining boolena mask is already vectorized, not necessary.

Comment: You are note using for loops anywhere nor do you tell what to return how will this code even work.

Comment: @AliasgherNooruddin - Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add expected output? I guess you need Series or numpy array filled by `True`s and `False`s by your conditions.